# for each loop over XML elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am looking for a way to do a for each loop over XML that is returned from an ajax request. I have the below code which logs the value of the id attribute of the first success element.

How can I change this to go over all 20,50,70 etc success elements and print the values of their id attribute?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: {},
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var id = $(xml).find('success').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
    }   
});
```

Example XML:

```
<body>
<success id="1" ></success>
<success id="2" ></success>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your XML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
   var id = $(xml).find('success').attr('id');
   console.log(id);
```

To:

```
   $(xml).find('success').each(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       console.log(id);
   });
```

Reference:

-- [**jQuery.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```js
var xml = '<body>\
<success id="1" ></success>\
<success id="2" ></success>\
</body>';
xml = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xml).find('success').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```